# On Button Click Print PDF from Server

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, printing, onclick, adobe

I am spinning my wheels on this one. I have a asp.net site using vb.net. I link to this ASP.net site through intranet SharePoint pages. I have some code that generates a pdf file from an SSRS report. Now in the same lines of code I'd like to print the pdf file. I've found this do so but with no luck in getting it to work:

```
    ''''PRINT REPORT
    ''get default printer
    Dim oPS As New System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings
    Dim defaultprintername As String = ""
    Try
        'Set my print ---- defaultprintername = "Dell 3330dn Laser Printer XL"
        defaultprintername = oPS.PrinterName
    Catch ex As System.Exception
        defaultprintername = ""
        SendAllLabel.Text = "ERROR - Could not set printer"
    Finally
        oPS = Nothing
    End Try

    Dim pathToExecutable As String = "AcroRd32.exe"
    Dim starter As New ProcessStartInfo(pathToExecutable, "/t " + strReportOutput + " " + defaultprintername + "")
    Dim Process As New Process()
    Process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    Process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = True
    Process.StartInfo.Verb = "print"
    Process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    Process.StartInfo = starter
    ''WILL NOT START BUT NO EXCEPTION
    Try
        Process.Start()
        Process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    Catch ex As System.Exception
        SendAllLabel.Text = "ERROR - Could not set print job."
    End Try

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000)

    Process.CloseMainWindow()
    Dim iLoop As Int16 = 0
    'check the process has exited or not
    If Process.HasExited = False Then
        Try
            Process.Kill()
        Catch ex As Exception
            SendAllLabel.Text = "ERROR - Could not stop process."
        End Try
        'if not then loop for 100 time to try and close the process'with 10 seconds delay
        While Not Process.HasExited
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000)
            Process.CloseMainWindow()
            iLoop = CShort(iLoop + 1)

            If iLoop >= 100 Then 


                Try
                    Process.Kill()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    SendAllLabel.Text = "ERROR - Could not stop process."
                End Try
                Exit While
            End If
        End While
    End If

    Process.Close()
    Process.Dispose()
    Process = Nothing
    starter = Nothing
```

What needs to be done to get this to work? I see many sites referencing this code but nothing beyond what it is. Do I need to grant permissions? If so how do I do that? The server is using Adobe Reader 10.0 and most users are using Reader 11.0.

Please and Thank you

Comment: You do realize that if you are telling it to print in the ASP code, you are asking it to print on your server, not the clients computer... right?

Comment: You can open the PDF in a new web browser and this will give you print option. Would this suffice ?

Comment: The default printer on the server is the printer that it needs to go to for the client.

Comment: Also it would suffice to open a new web browser that will give them a print option.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate the PDF and then stream it down to the browser, here is something I wrote ages ago.

```
   Response.Clear()
    Response.ClearHeaders()
    Response.ClearContent()

    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"

    ' IE & Acrobat seam to require "content-disposition" header being in the response.  If you don't add it, the doc still works most of the time, but not always.
    ' this makes a new window appear: 
    ' you can replace the filename with the actual filename
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=something.PDF")

    ' Create a new memory stream that will hold the pdf output
    Dim memStream As New System.IO.MemoryStream()

    ' Export the report to PDF:
    ' put the pdf file into the memStream
    ' the strpath variable should hold the full path and filename of the pdf file
    ' for example dim strPath = "\\hw.net\files\2014dt140305.105459.pdf"
    Dim bData As Byte()
    Dim br As BinaryReader = New BinaryReader(System.IO.File.OpenRead(strPath))
    bData = br.ReadBytes(br.BaseStream.Length)
    Dim memStream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(bData, 0, bData.Length)

    ' Write the PDF stream out
    Response.BinaryWrite(memStream.ToArray())

    ' Send all buffered content to the client
    Response.End()
```

Comment: The file is located on a company shares drive. How would I open the file if it was something like: \\Hw\files\2014dt140305.105459.pdf

Comment: sorry that wasn't the full link... \\hw.net\files\2014dt140305.105459.pdf

Comment: I've edited my answer to include the code to read the pdf into the memorystream object